# XCode - Moving Buttons to Navigationbar doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift

I want the two buttons on the buttom of the DetailView to be in the Navigation Bar. If i drag them there, they become invisible. If i embed the DetailView in a NavigationController, then the app crashes if i click on a cell.

Here i have a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLjql.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in the navigation bar, the left bar button is created automaticly (the Back button), but you can add the right bar button, and it shouldn't dissapear.

What I do, to avoid this kind of problems, is that I hide the navigation in all views, and create my own, using the UIView (UIBlurEffect in iOS 8, or UIImage), and I can just as easly navigate between controllers, as I would with the Navigation bar.

Comment: But why crashes the app when i add a navigationcontroller, even if the buttons stay at their actual positions?
I just want to move them to the navi-bar for design reasons.

sorry btw, this is my first time programming with swift and xcode.

Comment: Sure, we've all been there. What does the error/exception say, or at which line does it crash?

Comment: ok, i got it. Was my fault, i didn't implement the seque. thank you!